# Redirecting wildcard subdomains to a different top-level domain with nginx

Tags: ssl, redirect, https, nginx, url-rewriting

We have a bunch of wildcard subdomains (_foo.example.com, bar.example.com, etc) that, when accessed via HTTPS should redirect to the equivalent subdomain on our secure domain.

Some examples:

- https://foo.example.com => https://foo.secure.com
- https://foo.example.com/some/path => https://bar.secure.com/some/path
- https://bar.example.com => https://bar.secure.com

I think this can be accomplished with nginx rewrites but I'm not sure about the syntax.  Here's what I'm attempting:

```
server {
    listen        443;
    server_name   *.example.com;

    rewrite       ^(.*)   https://*.secure.com$1 permanent;
}
```

This obviously won't work because I'm not capturing the incoming subdomain and using it in the rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this (untested):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default ssl;

    server_name "~^(?<name>\w\d+)\.example\.com$";

    rewrite ^(.*) https://$name.secure.com$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution and it's working for me (heavily modified for my own purpose).

Answer (score 0):

Found this on http://forum.slicehost.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=730

```
# redirects arbitrary subdomain (some.random.sub.example.com) to (some.random.sub.example.org)
if ($host ~* "^([^.]+(\.[^.]+)*)\.example.com$"){
  set $subd $1;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$subd.example.org$1 permanent;
  break;
}

# Simply redirects example.com to example.org
if ($host ~* "^example.com$"){
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://example.org$1 permanent;
  break;
}
```